# Нет картинки с orangePi 4 lts на armbian

Tags: orange-pi, armbian-linux

У меня есть orangePi 4 lts с официального сайта я скачал Ubuntu для микрокомпьютера. Картинка была.
Поставил armbian (https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-4-lts/) картинка с hdmi не поступает, могу подключится только по SSH.